# Additional configuration file for SwiftFormat

Tags: swift, configuration, format, swiftformat

There is interesting thing in [documentation of SwiftFormat](https://github.com/nicklockwood/SwiftFormat#config-file):

> Config files named ".swiftformat" will be processed automatically,
> however, you can select an **additional configuration file** to use for
> formatting using the --config "path/to/config/file" command-line
> argument. A configuration file selected using --config does not need
> to be named ".swiftformat", and can be located outside of the project
> directory.

May be I have some miss-understand, but I thought that I can add second configuration file and override in it some properties from `.swiftformat`.
I've add my custom configuration near `.swiftformat` configuration, and launch swiftformat with command:

```
swiftformat —config .custom_config
```

SwiftFormat use only configuration in `.custom_config`, but does not use configuration in `.swiftformat`.
Can I make additional custom configuration to launch it in come cases whithout copy all content of default configuration in my custom file?